# findViewById in custom view instantiated from XML - when does the layout become available

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, custom-controls

#### some_layout.xml with a custom viewgroup and a child

```
<com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.ShowcaseView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/ShowcaseView">
    <include
        layout="@layout/showcase_button"
        android:id="@id/showcase_button"/>
</com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.ShowcaseView>
```

#### ShowcaseView.java - when can i access R.id.showcase_button in the custom viewgroup

```
private Button mEndButton;

public ShowcaseView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // cannot be found at this stage, returns null
    mEndButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showcase_button);
}
```

#### What View or ViewGroup method should I override or what event should I observe?

- In an Activity the view becomes available after setContentView, but what is the lifecycle of a custom view constructed from an XML file?
- What is the earliest point where findViewById(R.id.showcase_button) will succeed, so as to assign the field?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29

Comment: @Luksprog just tried the findViewById in onFinishInflate() but it is still null? is that maybe because children of a viewgroup may not yet be inflated yet?

Comment: The children would be inflated at that point(along with other nested children). How does the `showcase_button` layout like? Also , did you declare somewhere else the id `@id/showcase_button` and why(use @+id/showcase_button)?

Comment: @Luksprog i tried with this as well <Button android:id="@+id/showcase_action" android:text="Basd" style="@style/Wrap"/> - i.e. using a new id and no include, but still null

Comment: I don't see why would that happen, the `onFinishInflate()` method is where all children should be available, if this fails you must be doing something else in your code. Do you at least see that button?

Comment: log getChildCount() in onFimishJnflate, what you see?

Comment: getChildCount() is 1 and getChildAt(0).getClass().getSimpleName() is Button, but getChildAt(0).getId() is different from R.id.showcase_action (even if using Button directly) ??